# how to quickly reboot from OSX to Windows and back

Tags: bootcamp, automator

From Windows back to OSX is fairly easy.  What I would like is a few less steps to get from OSX to Windows.  Currently I launch system preferences -> startup disk - then select the bootcamp partition and press restart.

Being completely new to OSX it seems to me that a one-click action on the dock should be possible with some sort of automation scripting.  Howerver I know nothing about OSX (yet) and how that works. First, is such a thing possible, and second please provide some tutoral links for such automation system.

Comment: What was the "fairly easy" way from windows? Just opening the bootcamp tray?

Comment: @noelicus Yes, right click the bootcamp icon and pick Reboot in OS X.  It may be interesting to know that since this original post I have moved away from bootcamp to parallels (which on a late 2013 iMac (32GB ram, 3TB fusion etc...) it's really a much better environment.  Now just a two finger swipe back and forth between the two Operating systems.

Comment: It seems there's no way of doing a "boot once to OS X". That bootcamp menu in windows seems to change the permanent start-up.
On another note, I have installed parallels also. Very cool, but slower than a native boot!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> Note: This does not work on systems with [System Integrity Protection](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899) enabled

Write a shell script that does this

```
#!/bin/sh
# tell OSX to change the boot disk 
# nextonly just for the next time - without the default would be Windows
/usr/sbin/bless -mount /Volumes/BOOTCAMP --setBoot  --nextonly  
# reboot
/sbin/shutdown -r now
```

This can be called from a terminal window

```
sudo bootcamp
```

The use Automator to call this via an apple script and save as an application

```
on run {input, parameters}

    do shell script "/Users/mark/bin/bootcamp" with administrator privileges

    return input
end run
```

Comment: Just keep in mind that when you click on this script, you wont have the chance to save any unsaved work from any application. The system WILL reboot your machine whatever the cost!

Comment: Shouldn't it be --mount /Volumes/BOOTCAMP --setBoot  --nextonly  (notice double dashes before parameters)?

Comment: Can someone verify that this works on OSX 10.10 or greater? Even with the double dashes it doesn't work for me (just restarts into OSX). I've verified that the command doesn't throw any errors by running it directly on the command line and verified that /Volumes/BOOTCAMP exists.

Comment: I'm also unable to get it to work on macOS 10.12.2. When I invoke `sudo bless --mount /Volumes/BOOTCAMP --setBoot --nextonly`, I get the error `Could not set boot device property: 0xe00002bc`. Seems [the issue is SIP](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32952725/70170).

Comment: If you change the first line to `#!/bin/sh -e`, the system will only reboot if the bless command succeeds.

Comment: This no longer works due to System Integrity Protection. See [this](https://twocanoes.com/how-el-capitan-boot-camp-is-affected-by-apples/) and @celestialroad's answer to this question.

Answer (score 17):

Another way to get from OS X to Windows quickly is to use [Bootchamp](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/28468/bootchamp), which adds a menu bar item like this:

[image]

For my Windows-booting needs Bootchamp has worked well.

(I learned about it from a [similar question on Super User](https://superuser.com/q/36266/2984) I once asked.)

Comment: BootChamp doesn't work with certain setup and it will take up additional seconds to when booting up the computer.

Comment: With El Capitan, BootChamp doesn't work anymore :( - http://kainjow.tumblr.com/post/128933657269/bootchamp-and-el-capitan

Comment: I installed this and 'restart in windows' is greyed out?

Answer (score 14):

Hold <kbd>⌥</kbd> while booting, you'll get a prompt to choose which OS / drive you want to boot from!

Comment: This is not what he asked, it's definitely not "quick" nor "automated" nor "one-click".

Comment: @looris sometimes there's no need to re-invent the wheel..

Comment: @nuc With 38K views, I'd say there is. Lohoris has the right of it.

Comment: The question was "What I would like is a few less steps to get from OSX to Windows."  This solves the problem easily (exactly what I was looking for when I found this question), doesn't require new software, or scripting.

Answer (score 6):

Here is an Automator workflow I wrote to accomplish rebooting to Bootcamp automatically:

https://github.com/ryanmcginnis/Restart-to-Bootcamp

As of El Capitan, it is no longer possible to programmatically set the startup disk, even with SIP disabled.

Comment: This is a nice and simple solution. Works great. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is creating a shortcut to `System Preferences / Startup Disk` on your dock in which you can quickly change the startup disk to boot into Windows, directly.

For this, drag the `StartupDisk.prefPane` from `/System/Library/PreferencePanes/` into the right side of your dock:

[image: Dragging the StartupDisk.prefPane into the dock]

Now, you can click it, unlock it, select BOOTCAMP and hit restart. This works especially well on newer MacBooks, because you can use Touch ID to unlock.

[image: Progressing to reboot into Windows]

Comment: This is the current only solution, because of the updates done on macOS.

Answer (score 2):

I'm really fond of [rEFIt](http://refit.sourceforge.net/).

> rEFIt is a boot menu and maintenance toolkit for EFI-based machines like the Intel Macs. You can use it to boot multiple operating systems easily, including triple-boot setups with Boot Camp. It also provides an easy way to enter and explore the EFI pre-boot environment.

The OP seems to be interested about an OSX-to-Windows only command, so I guess this is not exactly what he wants. Still, I find rEFIt much easier to work with: if I want to go from one OS to another, I just need to reboot and then choose the OS I want.

And if you ever need to work with 3 (or more) OS'es, you will see rEFIT is a much better option...

It also allows you to boot up from an external hard drive or a pen drive, which is a very nice bonus.

**Edit** From the rEFIt page:

> 2013-03-29: As you may have noticed, rEFIt is no longer actively maintained. Please check out [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/), a fork that is maintaned and under active development.

Answer (score 2):

It seems this script from SuperUser handles the closing of open windows (and stopping the scheduled restart if user presses 'cancel'):

```
do shell script "hdiutil unmount /Volumes/<Windows_Partition> -quiet"
do shell script "bless -device /dev/disk0s3 -legacy -setBoot -nextonly" with administrator privileges
tell application "Finder" to restart
```

Comment: error "Could not set boot device property: 0xe00002e2" number 3

Answer (score 2):

Quick boot does it nicely. It's in the menu bar.[image]

**http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/25414/quickboot**

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to use AppleScript instead of BootChamp since I had a problems with an always-running webapp when it resumed state when returning to OS X instead of launching regularly. Trying to bless the volume from an AppleScript did not work on my iMac with a 3TB fusion drive so rebooting after the bless would lead to an error screen "NO BOOTABLE DEVICE - INSERT BOOT DISC AND PRESS ANY KEY".

What I had to do was bless the HDD's EFI disk id with the **-device** switch, mount the BootCamp volume with the **-mount** switch and skip the **-legacy** switch. For me the HDD's EFI partition disk id was disk1s1 but you can verify yours by running *diskutil list* in terminal and look for the EFI device from the HDD (not the SSD).

I also wanted to do a "clean" restart so my applications would not resume when returning to OS X so I created an AppleScript that quits specific apps before continuing to the bless and reboot:

```
try
    set apps to {"Safari", "Google Chrome", "Mail", "Twitter"}
    repeat with thisApp in apps
        tell application thisApp to quit
    end repeat
end try

delay 2

do shell script "bless -device /dev/disk1s1 -mount /Volumes/BOOTCAMP -setBoot -nextonly" password "YourPassWordHere" with administrator privileges
tell application "Finder" to restart
```

You could skip the part about the password if you don't want to store your admin password in the script in plaintext.

If you put the script or an alias of it to **~/Library/Scripts** and enable the *Script Menu* from Script Editor's preference you get an easy way to run it like with BootChamp.

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for a useful way for several years, and I can't bear it anymore. So I learned Swift and wrote a macOS Menu Bar app that takes you from macOS to Windows in at least 3 clicks. That's the fastest, safest, and easiest way I know to boot from Windows on the latest macOS.

[iBoot](https://github.com/lbwanghr/iBoot) is available on GitHub and an instructional video on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=te4bWl2PwoM&t=16s).