# Set EFI to boot Windows via (U)EFI one time

Tags: windows, startup, efi, bless

On my late 2012 Mac Mini, I have installed both Mac OS X Mavericks (with FileVault) and Windows 8.1 (natively, not via Bootcamp):

```
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     268.4 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage                         859.0 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
   4:         Microsoft Reserved                         134.2 MB   disk0s4
   5:       Microsoft Basic Data Windows                 140.2 GB   disk0s5
```

That's working fine, and I can boot both Mac OS and Windows.
However, I'd like to be able to boot my Mac into Windows from the command line - without permanently changing boot settings.

To my understanding, this should do it: `sudo bless -mount "/Volumes/Windows" -setBoot --nextonly`

The command produces no output. With `--verbose`, it tells me this:

```
EFI found at IODeviceTree:/efi
Mount point for /Volumes/Windows is /Volumes/Windows
Mount point is '/Volumes/Windows'
No BootX creation requested
No boot.efi creation requested
found ioreg "FirmwareFeaturesMask"; featureMaskValue=0xE003FF37
found ioreg "FirmwareFeatures"; featureFlagsValue=0xE001F537
isPreBootEnvironmentUEFIWindowsBootCapable=1
given BSD is not a DVD disc medium
isDVDWithElToritoWithUEFIBootableOS=0
Checking if disk is complex (if it is associated with booter partitions)
GPT detected
Booter partition required at index 6
System partition found
Preferred system partition found: disk0s1
Returning booter information dictionary:
<CFBasicHash 0x7fdc0940a7c0 [0x7fff73d4beb0]>{type = mutable dict, count = 3,
entries =>
    0 : <CFString 0x101f48e70 [0x7fff73d4beb0]>{contents = "System Partitions"} = (
    disk0s1
)
    1 : <CFString 0x101f49650 [0x7fff73d4beb0]>{contents = "Data Partitions"} = (
    disk0s5
)
    2 : <CFString 0x101f49670 [0x7fff73d4beb0]>{contents = "Auxiliary Partitions"} = (
)
}

Path to mountpoint given: /Volumes/Windows
IOMedia disk0s5 has UUID D4FC6318-275B-427D-B039-3AB033DE8ACC
Setting EFI NVRAM:
    efi-boot-next='<array><dict><key>IOMatch</key><dict><key>IOProviderClass</key><string>IOMedia</string><key>IOPropertyMatch</key><dict><key>UUID</key><string>D4FC6318-275B-427D-B039-3AB033DE8ACC</string></dict></dict><key>BLLastBSDName</key><string>disk0s5</string></dict></array>'
Setting EFI NVRAM:
    IONVRAM-DELETE-PROPERTY='efi-boot-file'
Setting EFI NVRAM:
    IONVRAM-DELETE-PROPERTY='efi-boot-mkext'
Setting EFI NVRAM:
    IONVRAM-DELETE-PROPERTY='efi-boot-kernelcache'
NVRAM variable "boot-args" not set.
```

That looks good to me - but the command has no effect, after rebooting, I'm back in Mac OS X.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I know this isn't via command line, but for testing purposes does [BootChamp](http://www.kainjow.com) work?

Comment: BootChamp sounds like a BootCamp-oriented software. I suspect it won't find my installation (the volume is not called `BOOTCAMP`), and would try a legacy-boot, which cannot work.

Comment: My Windows partition isn't through Boot Camp either, but it still works — it was just a suggestion to see if it could manage it.

Comment: One reboot later, the results are in: BootChamp successfully set my Mac to boot once... into BIOS hell: It took a few seconds at the gray screen (where the BIOS-CSM is loaded), and left me in a black screen with "No bootable device -- insert boot disk and press any key".

Answer (score 1):

I finally can boot to Bootcamp EFI partition with the help of [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/198680/167883).

In order to boot to Bootcamp EFI partition, you have to `bless` the `EFI` partition of the disk that you install Bootcamp, too. So it goes something like this: `bless -device /dev/disk0s1 -mount /Volumes/BOOTCAMP -setBoot -nextonly`.