# Is there a faster way to restart macOS Sierra into the bootcamp partition?

Tags: macos, bootcamp, startup

When I'm in windows under bootcamp all I need to do to restart into macOS is

- Right click the bootcamp icon in the task bar
- Select "reboot into macOS"

When I'm in macOS and I want to switch to windows I need to

- Click the apple in the upper left
- Select "System Preferences"
- Select "Startup Disk"
- Click the lock
- Enter administrator password
- Select "BOOTCAMP Windows"
- Click "Restart..."

Am I missing some obvious shortcut to reboot into windows, or is this really the best that Apple can do to support restarting into bootcamp?

If apple doesn't provide an easier way is there an app, script, or something that I can use to make the process of switching from macOS into windows a two click operation?

#### Note about duplicate:

Please be aware that this is an ongoing issue with macOS, and that over the years Apple has changed things so solutions that worked in the past no longer work now.

The duplicate question [how to quickly reboot from OSX to Windows and back](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9492/how-to-quickly-reboot-from-osx-to-windows-and-back) does have one answer that may work for macOS Sierra, but it's buried, the selected and most other answers do NOT work on this version of macOS.

I've edited the question title to clarify which version of macOS this question targets, and I expect we will need to have a question for each version of macOS so people can find the answer for their particular system, rather than digging through a long question and trying several "solutions" until the real solution for their setup is found.

<sub>- macOS Sierra 10.12.6 & Windows 7 Pro 64bit bootcamp on MacBook Pro (17-inch, Early 2011)</sub>

Comment: @Allan I've edited the question title to restrict it to macOS Sierra since solutions that work in other older versions do not work in this version, and that 6 year old question is too long and confusing to figure out what solution works in which version of macOS.

Comment: We don't need to have different questions/answers for each version of macOS.  The key is, if the solution works, then it's relevant.  What would make this not a dupe is if the solution presented doesn't work.  Assuming it only "may work for Sierra" isn't sufficient to disqualify it from being valid.  If the solution works - **you** can edit the dupe, update it and indicated that it works in Sierra making it current and relevant.

Comment: @Allan This discussion is complicated, and each stack exchange site does it differently.  Rather than hashing it out here I've created a meta question to ask the community what to do in the general case: https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3120/how-should-we-manage-questions-that-have-very-different-answers-per-version-of-m please read my argument there and consider posting an answer so I can better understand your position without the length limitations commenting presents.

Comment: How does the answer from that old question "not work"? Is there an error message when you run the command? Does the Mac simply reboot into macOS?

Comment: Nice the discussion above, but I still have not found the correct answer for doing this in Sierra...

Answer (score 2):

What I do.

Restart normally. When you hear the startup chime, press the option key. You will get a choice of OS, including BootCamp. Use the arrow key to select and press return.

Comment: That's not an unreasonable option, but it requires more attention. I have an older system that takes time to restart, even with the upgraded SSD, and I'd prefer to perform a quick action, tend to other tasks for a few minutes, then return to the computer with it running the expected OS.